# Can't make NSPredicate work on custom NSObject

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

I have an `NSSet` of custom objects called `SCPFLocation`, and I want to filter it with every location's human-readable format (a property called `interpretedForm`). Here's how I'm doing it:

```
NSMutableSet *set = [[SCPFLocation allLocations] mutableCopy];
[set filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"interpretedForm contains[c] '%@'", searchString]];
self.matches = [set.allObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [((SCPFLocation *)obj1).interpretedForm compare:((SCPFLocation *)obj2).interpretedForm];
}];
```

But I can't figure out why this isn't working. By the time the predicate filter is applied, `set` contains zero objects. What could I be doing wrong?

`SCPFLocation` is a subclass of `SCPFValue`, from which `SCPFLocation` inherits and overrides the `interpretedForm` property. Below is the `@interface` and `@implementation` of `SCPFLocation`.

```
@interface SCPFLocation : SCPFValue

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *province;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *city;

@end

@implementation SCPFLocation

- (NSString *)interpretedForm
{
    if (self.city) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", self.city, self.province];
    } else {
        return self.province;
    }
}

@end
```

And `SCPFValue.h`:

```
@interface SCPFValue : NSObject

/*! The human-readable representation of this @c SCPFValue.
 */
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *interpretedForm;

/*! A representation of this @c SCPFValue when it is being passed from and to the API.
 */
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *originalForm;

- (id)initWithInterpretedForm:(NSString *)interpretedForm originalForm:(NSString *)originalForm;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself, and the answer is quite frustrating. Instead of defining the predicate this way:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"interpretedForm contains[c] '%@'", searchString]
```

I did it this way:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"interpretedForm contains[c] '%@'", searchString]]
```

AND IT WORKED. I have no idea why the first form is problematic when it very much follows Apple's [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).

Comment: Hmm... that's essentially the same thing. The format/string thing just creates a string. You have just pushed it one step further away. Can you put the predicateWithFormat back just to triple check the text in it?

Comment: Yup, I put it back to the first form without `NSString` and it stopped working. Must be some kind of iOS bug? I'm building for iOS 7.

Comment: How about just doing - [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"interpretedForm contains[c] %@", searchString] - I don't think you need the single quotes around %@

Comment: The second format works without the single quotes! It also fails with double quotes. Strange.

Comment: @MattQuiros according to apple if you used predicateWithFormat it already encapsulates the string with ''. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-CJBDBHCB

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to cast objects inside blocks like this. I find this form easier to read.

```
NSMutableSet *set = [[SCPFLocation allLocations] mutableCopy];

[set filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"interpretedForm contains[c] '%@'", searchString]];

self.matches = [set.allObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(SCPFLocation *obj1, SCPFLocation *obj2) {
    return [obj1.interpretedForm compare:obj2.interpretedForm];
}];
```

Having said that. There is nothing in there that wouldn't work. How is it not working?

Can you show an example of an object and a search string that isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on casting. I'm quite sure the predicate is the problem though. `set` gets correctly initialized with all the location objects. I also tried filtering an `NSSet` of `NSString`s of the `interpretedForm`s instead, then I made the predicate `@"SELF contains[c] '%@'"` and it worked. I would very much like to keep it a set of `SCPFLocation` objects though. Could the format be wrong considering the subclassing and the overridden `interpretedForm` getter from `SCPFLocation`?

Comment: can you please set a breakpoint in the interpretedForm method to check if the method gets called during the filtering?

Comment: Yeah sorry. I wrote the answer first but then realised that I was looking at the wrong bit but then the answer was written so thought I'd leave it :D

Comment: It's getting called during filtering. :( @CarlJ

Comment: I just figured out the answer. Can someone explain why my solution worked, though?